# Finding normalization of nodal cubic

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

There are simliar questions here: [normalization of the nodal cubic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893783/normalization-of-the-nodal-cubic/1893789), [Normalization of a variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977623/normalization-of-a-variety), but I think my purpose of question is slightly different.

I am trying to show that $\operatorname{Spec} k[t] \to \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (t^2-1,t^3-t)$ is a normalization.

By basic theory it is enough to show that $k[t]$ is isomorphic to the integral closure of $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$.

I am try to follow the following steps:

1. Show that $k[t]$ and $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$ have the same fractional fields.
2. Show that $k[t]$ is integrally closed.
3. Show that $k[t]$ is contained in the integral closure of $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$.

For 1, I cannot see why the map $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)\to k[t]$ given above is injective. It is well-defined. If this is injective, then it induces an inclusion of fractional fields, and this inclusion must be in fact surjective because its image contains $t=y/x$.

I've shown 2: $k[t]$ is a UFD, and 3: $t=y/x$ satisfies the equation $t^2-x-1$. 2 and 3 show that $k[t]$ is the integral closure of $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$.

So what only left is showing injectivity of $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)\to k[t]$. Why does $f(t^2-1,t^3-t)=0$ imply $f(x,y) \in (y^2-x^3-x^2)$?

Comment: Please use `\operatorname{Spec}` to format $\operatorname{Spec}$ - it produces better spacing. I've made the upgrade for you this time.

Comment: Even though this isn't part of the question, I would like to remark why $h=y^2-(x^3+x^2)$ is irreducible: We use that irreducibility in $k(x)[y]$ implies irreducibility in $k[x][y]$ (irreducibility in $Q(R)[y]$ is equivalent to irreducibility plus primitivity in $R[x]$, for $R$ a domain). We have that $h$ is irreducible in $k(x)[y]$ iff $x^3+x^2$ does not have a square root in $k(x)$. Since $k[x]$ is a DFU, it's integrally closed in $Q(k[x])=k(x)$. Hence the latter condition amounts to $h$ does not have a square root in $k[x]$. But $x^3+x^2$ has odd degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $$f(x,y)=(y^2-x^3-x^2)g(x,y)+a(x)y+b(x).$$ We have $a(t^2-1)(t^3-t)+b(t^2-1)=0$. What can you say about the degrees of $a(t^2-1)(t^3-t)$, respectively $b(t^2-1)=0$?

Comment: The degree of $a(t^2-1)(t^3-t)$ is odd and the degree of $b(t^2-1)$ is even. Thanks.

Comment: In detail: First, we can express $f(x,y)$ in the above way by dividing $f$ in $(k[x])[y]$ by the polynomial $y^2-x^3-x^2$, for the latter is monic in $y$. Then, we want to show that $$\tag{1}\label{1}0=a(t^2-1)(t^3-t)+b(t^2-1)$$ implies $0=a(x)y+b(x)$ in $k[x,y]$. First note that if $a$ (resp., $b$) is not zero, then $a(t^2-1)$ (resp., $b(t^2-1)$) is a nonzero polynomial of even degree. Hence $a(t^2-1)(t^3-t)+b(t^2-1)$ is a sum two nonzero polynomials; one of odd degree with one of even degree. Thus, the sum vanishes iff $a(t^2-1)$ and $b(t^2+1)$ vanish. Hence \eqref{1} implies $a(x)=0=b(x)$.