# Hartshorne Chapter III: How to find an covering of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Hartshorne has an exercise given as follows (**Chatper III 10.6**):

> Let $Y$ be the plane nodal cubic curve $y^2=x^2(x+1)$. Show that $Y$
> has a finite etale covering $X$ of degree $2$, where $X$ is a union of two irreducible components, each one isomorphic to the normalization of $Y$.

This [question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363106/hartshorne-exercise-iii-10-6-etale-covering-of-the-nodal-cubic-curve) explores this exercise quite comprehensively. In particular, it says that the etale covering is given by the curve $\operatorname{Spec}k[s,t]/(t^2-(s^2-1)^2)$. While I understand why this candidate works, what's more puzzling to me is how one can approach this problem and arrive at this very curve.

What I understand is that we have a normalization of the curve $Y$: its the affine line with the morphism induced by $t\mapsto (t^2-1,t(t^2-1))$; there are plenty of answer here that address this: for example this one and these ones: [Finding normalization of nodal cubic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165798/finding-normalization-of-nodal-cubic), [Normalization of a variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977623/normalization-of-a-variety), [normalization of the nodal cubic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893783/normalization-of-the-nodal-cubic/1893789), so I'm comfortable with this. In particular, it makes sense why this would be its normalization and the morphism describes a parametrization of the nodal cubic.

Now, with this knowledge equipped, how do one realize how to describe the curve $X$? We know that $X$ must be a union of two affine lines, where each is the normalization of $Y$ we saw earlier. Knowing just that, how do you the $X$ described as earlier is the correct idea? In fact, the irreducible components of $X$ are given by $\operatorname{Spec}k[s,t]/(t\pm(s^2-1))$; why are they isomorphic to the normalization of $Y$? Lastly, even if we knew the restriction morphism $(s,t)\mapsto (s^2-1,st)$ defined on $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ is the what describes $f$, how do we arrive at the description of $X$?

My question is quite fundamental: how does one approach questions of finding a (etale) covering of a given curve. For example, consider the cuspidal cubic curve $C=k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$. How does one go about finding an etale covering of $C$ of an appropriate degree? In fact, if it's possible, how does one go about finding etale coverings of the nodal cubic curve a given degree?

Any help will be extremely helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different way to realize the étale cover, inspired from the picture in Hartshorne (and as long as $\operatorname{char} k \neq 2$).

Set $C = \{y^2 = x^2(x+1)\} \subset \mathbb A^2$. The normalisation $\nu:\mathbb A^1 \to C, t \mapsto (t^2 - 1, t(t^2-1))$ factors over the closed immersion¹
$$\iota_1: \mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^3, t \mapsto (t^2 -1, t(t^2-1),t),$$
followed by the projection $p: \mathbb A^3 \to \mathbb A^2, (x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y)$. Clearly $p \circ \iota_1 = \nu$. You can also consider
$$\iota_2: \mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb A^3, t \mapsto (t^2 - 1, t(t^2-1), -t),$$
which also satisfies $p \circ \iota_2 = \nu$.

As [one can see](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/mvttvaas), the curves intersect in the three points
$$(0,0,1), (0,0,-1) \quad \text{and} \quad (-1,0,0).$$

*Exercise*. Those are the only intersection points.

So if we consider the union $X = \iota_1(\mathbb A^1) \cup \iota_2(\mathbb A^2)$, the map $X \to C$ is not étale at $P = (-1, 0,0)$, but étale everywhere else. Also, the maps $\iota_i(\mathbb A^1) \to C$ are étale at $P$, so we only have to separate the two points $\iota_1(0)$ and $\iota_2(0)$. To do this, consider the blow-up $\operatorname{Bl}_P(\mathbb A^3) \to \mathbb A^3$, and let $Y \subset \operatorname{Bl}_P(\mathbb A^3)$ be the strict transform of $X$. Then $Y \to C$ is étale.

---

I don't think a similar thing can be done for the cuspidal curve, because the cusp is locally irreducible, i.e. the completion $k[[x,y]] / (x^2 - y^3)$ is an integral domain. Since étale covers induce isomorphisms on completions², every connected étale cover over the cusp has to be irreducible.

---

¹ the $\iota_k$'s are closed immersions because they are basically graphs of the composition $\mathbb A^1 \xrightarrow{\nu} C \hookrightarrow \mathbb A^2$.

² I'm pretty sure this is true, but not totally sure if this holds in finite characteristic. Maybe someone more knowledgable could comment on that?

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! This gives a gorgeous geometric picture of the covering that captures all that we had been given, thank you so so much! It truly is a lovely answer :)

With this idea, I guess it would make sense to find an covering of higher degrees by going to larger space and projecting accordingly correct?

Comment: @PCeltide For degree $n$, you want $n$ normalisations which intersect in a kind of $n$-gon. I don't think you need a larger space, maybe $\iota_k: t \mapsto (t^2 - 1, t(t^2 - 1), (t+k)/(n-1))$ for $0 \leq k \leq n-2$ and $\iota_{n-1}: t \mapsto (t^2 -1, t(t^2-1), -t)$ works?

Comment: I see... So I just also noticed in the degree two case, there actually one more intersection point: $P=(-1,0,0)$ for $t=s=0$. These intersection points signify a kind of branching correct? For the point $P$, will that also be the case?.... For the degree $n$ as you've mentioned, the $\iota_{k}$ for $0\leq k\leq n-1$ do not intersect each other, but rather intersect $\iota_{n-1}$ at least once (more than once can happen: for example, consider the case $n=4$, $\iota_{2}$ intersects $\iota_3$ twice but the other just once.) Is this behaviors of intersections consistent with what we would expect?

Comment: Lastly, one last question: What would be the isomorphism to the curve $\operatorname{Spec}k[s,t]/(t^2-(s^2-1)^2)?$ that describes the covering?

Comment: @PCeltide You are right, I missed that additional point of intersection. Maybe a blow-up of $\mathbb C^3$ in that point would resolve it. I also have to think a bit more to see the isomorphism to the other curve.